# Find the highest scoring word in Python

Tags: python, function

I have managed to do it outside of a function, but now need help making it work within a function. At the moment, the code only looks at one word ("the") and produces only that value, then it stops. I can't get it to look at "the" and "testingg", then give me the one with the highest value.

```
def high(x):

    import string
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
    sentence = x.split()
    high_total = 0

    for word in sentence:
        total = 0
        for pos in word:
            if pos in alphabet:
                total += ord(pos) -96
    
        if total > high_total:
            high_total = total
            return (max(total))

print(high("the testingg"))
```

Comment: Because you `return` within the loop. `return high_total` outside the `for` loop. What is `max(total)` supposed to do?

Comment: store the highest scoring word in a variable, overwrite it if a new high score is found. return that word at the end of the function outside the loop.

Comment: @not_speshal hi there, thanks for the quick response. However, i'm not too sure what you mean, could you show me an example please?

Comment: Hi @PatrickArtner i'm not too sure what you mean, could you show me an example please?

Comment: @Uche24 - Move the `return` statement back by 2 tabs and change it to `return(high_total)`

Comment: @not_speshal deleted by other comment because it wasnt clear. But when i moved it, i get a  syntax error. "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function"

Answer (score 1):

Un-indent your return statement by 2 tabs and change it to `return(high_total)`:

```
def high(x):

    import string
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
    sentence = x.split()
    high_total = 0

    for word in sentence:
        total = 0
        for pos in word:
            if pos in alphabet:
                total += ord(pos) -96
    
        if total > high_total:
            high_total = total
            #returning here is returning within the for loop and the if block
        #returning here is still returning within the for loop
    #returning here is returning outside the for loop
    return high_total

>>> high("the testingg")
101
```

Comment: thank you once again, sorry still very new to using this platform, but is there a way i can message you directly with my code. When i put it in the comment, it's unreadable

Comment: No you can't. Why do you need to? This solves your question.